# Linux Mint on USB - mtab is a folder, not a file

Tags: linux, linux-mint, partition, live-usb

I just installed Linux Mint Maya (13.2) onto a USB stick with uNetbootin (http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/).  The install seems to work ok, and has a "persistence" partition which allows changes to persist between sessions.

One thing which is weird is that i can't do `df` to see the available space:

```
$ df -h
df: cannot read table of mounted file systems: Is a directory
```

I assume it's talking about `/etc/mtab`, and indeed when i look at mtab i can see it's not a file, it's a directory:

```
$ ls -l /etc
....
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      63 Jul 29 13:16 fstab
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root       3 Mar 30  2012 fstab.d
....
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Jul 29 12:03 mtab
-rw------- 1 root mint       0 Jul 29 11:43 mtab.fuselock
....
```

(i've just listed entries which i think are relevant).  When i look in `/etc/ls -l mtab` there's lots of links:

```
$ ls -l /etc/mtab
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Jul 29 11:29 ex -> /usr/bin/vim.basic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Jul 29 11:29 ex.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/vim.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Jul 29 11:29 ex.fr.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/fr/man1/vim.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Jul 29 11:29 ex.it.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/it/man1/vim.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Jul 29 11:29 ex.pl.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/pl/man1/vim.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Jul 29 11:29 ex.ru.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/ru/man1/vim.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Jul 29 12:03 gnome-text-editor -> /usr/bin/gedit
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Jul 29 12:03 gnome-text-editor.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/gedit.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jul 29 11:42 gnome-www-browser -> /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jul 29 11:42 google-chrome -> /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Jul 29 11:28 rview -> /usr/bin/vim.basic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Jul 29 11:28 rvim -> /usr/bin/vim.basic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Jul 29 11:28 vi -> /usr/bin/vim.basic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Jul 29 11:28 vi.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/vim.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Jul 29 11:28 vi.fr.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/fr/man1/vim.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Jul 29 11:28 vi.it.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/it/man1/vim.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Jul 29 11:28 vi.pl.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/pl/man1/vim.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Jul 29 11:28 vi.ru.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/ru/man1/vim.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Jul 29 11:29 view -> /usr/bin/vim.basic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Jul 29 11:29 view.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/vim.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Jul 29 11:29 view.fr.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/fr/man1/vim.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Jul 29 11:29 view.it.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/it/man1/vim.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Jul 29 11:29 view.pl.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/pl/man1/vim.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Jul 29 11:29 view.ru.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/ru/man1/vim.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Jul 29 11:28 vim -> /usr/bin/vim.basic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Jul 29 11:28 vimdiff -> /usr/bin/vim.basic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jul 29 11:42 x-www-browser -> /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
```

`fstab` seems normal, FWIW.

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
overlayfs / overlayfs rw 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nosuid,nodev 0 0
```

Does anyone know

1) what's going on with mtab here?

2) how i can fix it without cocking up my USB install (which has taken me ages to get working up to this point)

thanks! max

EDIT: (too long-winded for a comment) This is in response to an answer by @Celada pointing out that `/etc/mtab` looks like it's holding the contents of `/etc/alternatives`: that's right, it does!

`/etc/alternatives` is there as well, and has everything that's in `/etc/mtab`, plus lots more. (i've checked this by copying the contents into an array and subtracting one from the other).

Looking at the contents of `/etc/mtab`, the lines in there all refer to software i have installed since first booting the usb stick install:  namely, `vim`, (full version instead of the 'mini' one that comes with the install) `chrome` and `gedit` (a text editor).  As i said these lines are all in `/etc/alternatives` too.

I've done the following:

```
$ sudo mv /etc/mtab /etc/mtab_BACK
$ sudo ln -s /proc/mounts /etc/mtab
```

and now i can df again:

```
$ df -h
df: `/cow': No such file or directory
df: `/home/max/.gvfs': Transport endpoint is not connected
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs          4.0G  872M  2.9G  23% /
udev            1.2G  4.0K  1.2G   1% /dev
tmpfs           465M  984K  464M   1% /run
/dev/sdb1        15G  5.0G  9.8G  34% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      869M  869M     0 100% /rofs
/cow            4.0G  872M  2.9G  23% /
tmpfs           1.2G   16K  1.2G   1% /tmp
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.2G  144K  1.2G   1% /run/shm
```

The error message at the top is confusing:  `/cow` is listed (this is the persistence partition i think) but the error says `df: '/cow': No such file or directory`.  Is this a problem do you think?

Comment: I don't know if the missing `/cow` is normal or not. I seems erroneous, but it might be normal. Live Linux distributions with persistence partitions do some funny juggling at startup involving mounting the original, mounting the persistence partition, mounting a union of both, moving the originals out of the way, and moving the union in place. `/cow`'s non-existence might be a leftover artifact from that, I don't know. As for `/home/max/.gvfs`, that's nothing to worry about. That's a GNOME virtual filesystem that somehow got disconnected.

Comment: thanks - after a restart, the `/cow` error message is still there but the `.gvfs` one is gone.  `/etc/mtab` seems normal.  The line for `/cow` is `/cow / overlayfs rw,relatime,lowerdir=//filesystem.squashfs,upperdir=/cow 0 0
`, in case that's of interest.  Anyway, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file listing of `/etc/mtab` appears to belong to `/etc/alternatives`! Is there any way you could have accidentally renamed `/etc/alternatives` to `/etc/mtab`?

Is `/etc/alternatives` missing? If so, then the fix is just to rename `/etc/mtab` back to `/etc/alternatives`. If not, then you are stuck with the problem of merging the contents of the real `/etc/alternatives` with the `/etc/mtab` which is supposed to be `/etc/alternatives`.

Once `/etc/mtab` is moved out of the way, the easiest thing to do would be to just recreate it as a symlink to `/proc/mounts`:

```
ln -s /proc/mounts /etc/mtab
```

Comment: thanks @Celada - `/etc/alternatives` is there too and in fact has all of the lines from `/etc/mtab` plus a load of others.  (it looks like `/etc/mtab` just has entries for the 3 bits of software i've installed manually since booting up - gedit, chrome and vim).  So, theoretically i should be able to just ditch `/etc/mtab` and symlink it as you say.  I'll try renaming it first...

Comment: This looks like it's worked!  With a slight bit of oddness though - mind having a look at my edit?